# Angular2 Event Emmiter subscribe vs public variable?

Tags: events, angular, internationalization

I am doing a i18n service system for my Angular 2 application.
To avoid impure pipes, I am adding to the translation pipe an additional parameter, which change will trigger the pipe value to update, so it will update the translated text.

What would be the best practice: **Raise an event from the service and subscribe in each component to detect the language change**

vs

**Set the service variable `lang` as public and add to it to the pipe as parameter?**

I have tested and both of them works.

**Using Event emitter:**

component.html

```
<button md-button class="btn-register">{{'Register' | _:lang}}</button>
```

component.ts

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    loginForm: FormGroup;
    public lang: string;
    onLangChange: EventEmitter<LangChangeEvent>;

    constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder, private _authService: AuthService, private tr:TranslateService) {

    }

    ngOnInit():any {

        //monitor language change
        this.onLangChange = this.tr.onLangChange.subscribe( (event: LangChangeEvent) => {
            this.lang = event.lang;
        });

        this.loginForm = this._fb.group({
            email: ['', Validators.required],
            password: ['', Validators.compose( [Validators.required, hasNumbers] ) ]
        });

    }

    onSubmit(form) {
        this._authService.login( this.loginForm.value );
    }
}
```

translate.service.ts

```
import {Injectable, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {Languages} from "../config/Constants";

export interface LangChangeEvent {
    lang: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class TranslateService {

    public lang: string;
    dictionary: any = {};

    /**
     * An EventEmitter to listen to lang change events
     * onLangChange.subscribe((params: LangChangeEvent) => {
     *     // do something
     * });
     * @type {ng.EventEmitter<LangChangeEvent>}
     */
    public onLangChange: EventEmitter<LangChangeEvent> = new EventEmitter<LangChangeEvent>();

    constructor(private http: Http, private path:string) {

        let lang = this.detectLang();
        this.setLanguage(lang);
    }

    /**
     * A standard alias used for the translate function
     * @param val
     * @returns {string}
     * @private
     */
    public _(val: string) {
        return this.dictionary[val] ? this.dictionary[val] : val;
    }

    public setLanguage(lang: string) {

        if(Languages[lang]) {
            this.loadLanguage(lang, Languages[lang].path);
        }
    }

    private loadLanguage(lang:string, url: string) {
        return this.http.get(url).toPromise()
            .then( dictionary =>
            {
                this.dictionary = dictionary.json();
                this.lang = lang;
                this.onLangChange.emit({ lang: this.lang });
            })
            .catch( error => console.log(error) );
    }

    private detectLang(): string {
        if (typeof window === 'undefined' || typeof window.navigator === 'undefined') {
            return 'en';
        }
        let browserLang: any;
        if (typeof window.navigator['languages'] !== 'undefined' && window.navigator['languages'].length > 0) {
            browserLang = window.navigator['languages'][0].indexOf('-') !== -1 || window.navigator['languages'].length < 2 ? window.navigator['languages'][0] : window.navigator['languages'][1];
        } else {
            browserLang = window.navigator['language'] || window.navigator['browserLanguage'];
        }

        return browserLang && browserLang.length ? browserLang.split('-')[0] : 'en'; // use navigator lang if available
    }
}
```

**Using a public variable:**

```
<button md-button class="btn-register">{{'Register' | _:tr.lang}}</button>
```

component.ts

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    loginForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder, private _authService: AuthService, private tr:TranslateService) {

    }

    ngOnInit():any {

        this.loginForm = this._fb.group({
            email: ['', Validators.required],
            password: ['', Validators.compose( [Validators.required, hasNumbers] ) ]
        });

    }

    onSubmit(form) {
        this._authService.login( this.loginForm.value );
    }
}
```

translate.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {Languages} from "../config/Constants";

export interface LangChangeEvent {
    lang: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class TranslateService {

    public lang: string;
    dictionary: any = {};


    constructor(private http: Http, private path:string) {

        let lang = this.detectLang();
        this.setLanguage(lang);
    }

    /**
     * A standard alias used for the translate function
     * @param val
     * @returns {string}
     * @private
     */
    public _(val: string) {
        return this.dictionary[val] ? this.dictionary[val] : val;
    }

    public setLanguage(lang: string) {

        if(Languages[lang]) {
            this.loadLanguage(lang, Languages[lang].path);
        }
    }

    private loadLanguage(lang:string, url: string) {
        return this.http.get(url).toPromise()
            .then( dictionary =>
            {
                this.dictionary = dictionary.json();
                this.lang = lang;
            })
            .catch( error => console.log(error) );
    }

    private detectLang(): string {
        if (typeof window === 'undefined' || typeof window.navigator === 'undefined') {
            return 'en';
        }
        let browserLang: any;
        if (typeof window.navigator['languages'] !== 'undefined' && window.navigator['languages'].length > 0) {
            browserLang = window.navigator['languages'][0].indexOf('-') !== -1 || window.navigator['languages'].length < 2 ? window.navigator['languages'][0] : window.navigator['languages'][1];
        } else {
            browserLang = window.navigator['language'] || window.navigator['browserLanguage'];
        }

        return browserLang && browserLang.length ? browserLang.split('-')[0] : 'en'; // use navigator lang if available
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a hint. You shouldn't use `EventEmitter` for everything else than `@Output()` in a component. In services use `Observable` or `Subject` instead. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2

Comment: I removed the event emitter. I am keeping it with the public variable for the moment, as less code is needed

Comment: If you replace it by `Subject` there shouldn't be any difference except `next()` instead of `emit()`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  but that will keep me adding on every component the subscribe, instead by just using ``tr.lang`` exposing it as public variable I just need to inject the service

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your last comment. Why would you not need to subscribe when you use `EventEmitter`. `EventEmitter` currently just extends `Observable` or `Subject` but that's not guaranteed to stay this way.

Comment: I will add the code with my current solution

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer when the ``lang`` variable of the TranslateService changes, it will refresh the pipe value, rather than using an Observable, I just declare it as public and attached to the pipe ``{{'Register' | _:tr.lang}}``. It this  good practice in your opinion, or is better to go through an Observable/Subject?

Comment: If you change `EventEmitter` in the service by `Subject` it will behave the same. This is not related to your original question. This is only about that `EventEmitter` should not be used for anything but `@Output()`s. I think it doesn't make much difference if you use `lang` or `tr.lang` except that the view (template) is coupled to the service if you use `tr.lang` and otherwise only the component is coupled to the service but the view isn't.

Comment: For my library [angular2localization](https://github.com/robisim74/angular2localization) I used the pure pipes, with a public variable as a parameter to simplify the use in components through a `getter` of the language. The services still emit events because they are useful in several cases.